# How to skip some empty rows in csv file and continue reading rows with data?

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I am using buffer-reader to read data from a .csv file, some of the rows of the the .csv file are empty, I want to skip those rows and read data from rows which have data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression while reading the csv file like this one

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("csv.csv")));

        String currentLine;
        while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null){
            if(currentLine.matches("(\\d+)(,\\s*\\d+)*")){
                doWhateverYouWant(currentLine);
            }else{
                System.out.println(String.format("Invalid line: %s", currentLine));
            }
        }
```

Edit: If you are using JDK8, this approach is simpler

```
reader.lines().filter(line -> line.matches("(\\d+)(,\\s*\\d+)*"))
```

For the input (note the blank line between the 2nd row and the 4th)

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4

1,2,3,4
```

Shows the following output

```
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
Invalid line: 
1,2,3,4
```

Answer (score 0):

To ignore blank lines, add this check to make sure the line has something:

```
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
if(line.length() > 0) {
  //do lots of stuff to sort the data into lists etc
}           
}
```